# Solve matrix equation $AX = 2X + B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Solve the matrix equation $AX = 2X + B$ where $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 3  & 0 & 0    \cr 0 & 1 & -1 \cr 0 & 1 & 4  \end{bmatrix} \quad\text{ and }\quad B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\cr -1 & 1 \cr 0 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$$

I understand that it should be like $$X = (A - 2E)^{-1} B$$ but what is the inverse of $-2E$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: you need the inverse of $A-2E$ not of $-2E$

Comment: You don't have to find inverse of $-2E$ or that is, $-2I_3$. You need $(A-2I_3)^{-1}$

Comment: ok, then how to find $A−2E$?

Comment: $A-2E$ will be a block matrix. I am sure you can find the inverse of a $2\times 2$ matrix. So do that for the lower $2\times 2$ block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $A_{m\times m}$ and $B_{n\times n}$ be two square and invertible matrices; therefore$$\begin{bmatrix}A_{m\times m}&0_{m\times n}\\0_{n\times m}&B_{n\times n}\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}A^{-1}_{m\times m}&0_{m\times n}\\0_{n\times m}&B^{-1}_{n\times n}\end{bmatrix}$$